# SSL port 443 not responding and https not working

Tags: ssl, port, https

I have successfully setup SSL using CERTBOT on my NGIX server. However when I tried to use https://domainame I'm getting a not responding response.

`netstat -ano | grep 443` gives me the following results

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.78:33852      34.213.133.213:443      ESTABLISHED keepalive (424.33/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
```

`nc -vz domainname 443` says that port 443 refused to connect

My `ufw status is inactive`

What's wrong and how can fix the issue?

Thank you

Comment: What is the OS and what is in the logs?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.4, what logs would you require? Thank @NasirRiley

Comment: If you add the `-p` option to `netstat` and run it as root, it'll tell you what is listening on port 443 (I find `netstat -tlnp` is best).  Hopefully it is `nginx`. Also, does `domainname` resolve correctly?

Comment: The logs for the webserver that you are using. I'm assuming that it's Nginx. Do you understand the logging for it?